# Bash missing $(HOME) variable

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have been compiling an application using `Makefile` for quite a while without any problems. Today, I realized that my `Makefile` wasn't working any longer. A bit of debugging and I soon found out that `$(HOME)` was not defined

```
$echo $(HOME)
-bash: HOME: command not found
```

I always thought that `$HOME` and `$(HOME)` could be used interchangeably. Is there a reason why a system could be configured to avoid the use of `$(HOME)`?

Comment: Make and Bash use different syntaxes. Running code for one in the other is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `${HOME}`, not `$(HOME)`.

`$(HOME)` would expand to the output of a `HOME` command. Since there (probably) is no such command, you'll get an error message.

However, `$(HOME)` is the correct syntax in a Makefile. If you need help debugging your Makefile, you'll need to show us what's in it -- or, better, a small Makefile that exhibits the same problem.  A `make` rule like:

```
target:
        echo $(HOME)
```

should print the path of your home directory when you run `make target`.

In the shell, you can refer to the `HOME` variable as `$HOME` or as `${HOME}`; the latter can avoid problems with adjacent tokens.

In a Makefile, you can use either `$(HOME)` or `${HOME}`, but the `$(HOME)` form is more common. You can omit the parentheses only when the variable name is one character long (but even then you should use them for clarity). (Nobody has claimed that `make` is a model of clear and intuitive syntax.)

Comment: That should definitely be a comment and a close vote. You should know better

Comment: @hek2mgl: I disagree. Feel free to vote to close if you want to.

Comment: @hek2mgl I actually think it is constructive

Comment: It is a syntax error. That's by definition a close vote. It is literally stated in the close vote reasons. A question on the same quality level would be: I'm assigning a variable like `a == 1`; but `a` is still undefined...

Comment: A "simple typographical error" is a reason for a close vote. Misunderstanding shell syntax is not, in my opinion, a typo. Do you have a citation for your statement that syntax errors are *by definition* a reason to close a question?

Comment: I'm out here. 6up is definitely too much, but that's not your fault. It's a nonsense question imo.

Comment: @KeithThompson I read that again today and I need to say that having the fact that the OP explicitly pointed to the Makefile syntax makes a little difference between this and other obviously off-topic questions. Probably I over reacted here.